# How to enable Document ID service

Tags: 2010, document-id

I'm trying to use the document ID service on my SharePoint 2010 development instance, but it's not present within the "Site Collection Features".  Any ideas?

[image: Site Collection Features]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Activate it from PowerShell.

```
Enable-SPFeature -id docid -url [url]
```

[update]

The silly me put chevrons around the param url!

Also this is NOT available in SharePoint foundation.

Comment: I get the error; Enable-SPFeature : The Feature is not a Farm Level Feature and is not found in a Site level defined by the Url http://sptestserver/.

Comment: From your message I'm sure you put the url in correctly even though I never realised the code filter removed my chevrons. So I presume you are using foundation which doesn't include this feature.

Comment: @wonea are you using sharepoint foundation? If not then the install may be corrupt, and you need to reinstall sharepoint on the box.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Sharepoint 2010 Foundation.  Does Sharepoint 2013 Foundation have any Document ID features?

Comment: I actually don't have a test box up at the moment to look for 2013 and MSDN doesn't tell you sorry. From a google search though it does exist in 2013.